# Retrieve downloadable link in cdsapi python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, cds

After the execution of cdsapi in the local environment got an output like this.

> Result(content_length=54619844844,content_type=application/x-netcdf,location=https://download-0010.copernicus-climate.eu/cache-compute-0010/cache/data4/adaptor.mars.internal-1614159986.9020853-5507-18-2e9fe637-4442-4817-b4da-b8af35c1a342.nc)

I want to separate the location link from the Result()... The type of Result() is

Comment: Would indexing work? `result = what-ever-you-have`, and then result[0], result[1]...etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Noo that doesnot work ! Do you know how to get the aggregrate data like mean,max and min using cdsapi ?